# Why aren't my QML items being scaled when I move the window to a screen with a different DPI?

Tags: qt, windows-10, qml, dpi

I am using Windows 10 and Qt 5.15.1. When I move my QML application window from a low DPI screen (100% scale) to a high DPI (125% scale) screen, the window scales up (resizes) to use more pixels, as expected. This makes the window appear to be the same physical size on both screens.

However the items in the window do not scale -- they stay the same number of pixels. So all the items appear to be physically smaller on the high DPI screen.

How do I get the items to scale (to the same physical size) when I move the window between screens with different DPIs? I want this to occur with all items, like text, buttons, rectangles, etc.

My QML is:

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 240
    height: 60

    Text {
        text: "Hello World"
        font.pointSize: 14
    }

}
```

My Python is:

```
QtCore.QCoreApplication.setAttribute(Qt.AA_EnableHighDpiScaling)
QtCore.QCoreApplication.setAttribute(Qt.AA_UseOpenGLES)

app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])

engine = QtQml.QQmlEngine()
context = QtQml.QQmlContext(engine.rootContext())
designer = QtQml.QQmlComponent(engine, 'main.qml')
designer.create(context)

app.exec_()
```

[image: Actual and expected screenshots of text. The text is not scaled up as expected on the high DPI screen.]

Comment: Do you have this line in your main.cpp: `QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I learned that [Qt rounds DPI scaling](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-62914) to integers by default. So on my screen with 125% scaling, it was rounded down to 100%... thus no change.

This behavior can be disabled [as of Qt 5.14](https://lists.qt-project.org/pipermail/development/2019-September/037434.html) by setting the `QT_SCALE_FACTOR_ROUNDING_POLICY` environment variable to `PassThrough`. Or in code:

```
QtGui.QGuiApplication.setHighDpiScaleFactorRoundingPolicy(
    Qt.HighDpiScaleFactorRoundingPolicy.PassThrough)
```

Alternatively, if you know the scale factors of your monitors, you can specify them directly by setting the `QT_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTORS` environment variable like `QT_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTORS=1.25\;1`.

So now I get the expected automatic scaling on both of my screens.

[image: Scaled properly at 100% and 125%]

Comment: Good to know! Glad you got it figured out.

Answer (score 1):

It's actually weird to me that using a higher DPI changes the dimensions of your app. It's not really "scaling" it though. It's just making the window bigger. And you're not tying the size of the `Rectangle` to the `ApplicationWindow`, so that's why it stays the same size. The simple answer here is you could do this:

```
    Rectangle {
        anchors.fill: parent
        color: "green"
    }
```

That would keep the Rectangle at the same size as the application.

If you actually want all of the contents of the app (including children of the Rectangle) to scale as the ApplicationWindow changes size, then you could do something like this:

```
ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: defaultWidth
    height: defaultHeight

    property real defaultWidth: 320
    property real defaultHeight: 240

    Rectangle {
        width: defaultWidth
        height: defaultHeight
        color: "green"

        transform: Scale { 
            xScale: parent.width / defaultWidth
            yScale: parent.height / defaultHeight
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: My problem is that the rectangle is not being scaled to be the same visual size to the user. Only the window is being resized properly. Text has the same issue--the text is the same number of pixels on both my higher and lower DPI screens. On the high DPI screen the text ought to be scaled up and use more pixels so that it appears to be the same physical size on both screens.

Comment: Did you try my second example? That should scale the text too.

Comment: I don't want to tie my controls to the size of the window. I just want them to scale properly. Suppose I replaced the `Rectangle` with just `Text`.

Comment: I'll update my question because I think the `Rectangle` is misleading.